# cannot access an already disposed object serviceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, factory-pattern, mediator

I have a mediator class like this where I initialize a dictionary with a bunch of services:

```
public class Mediator : IMediator
    {
        static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, Func<IGameBaseService>> services = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Func<IGameBaseService>>();
        protected readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public Mediator(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        public async Task<Func<IGameBaseService>> GetGameServiceAsync(int gameId)
        {
            if (services.Count == 0)
                await AddServices();
            return await Task.FromResult(services[gameId]);
        }

        private async Task AddServices()
        {
            await Task.FromResult(services.GetOrAdd((int)Game.Blackjack, () => new LotteryService(_serviceProvider)));
        }
```

I call GetStateAsync like this to get the game state:

```
public async Task<ResponseBase> GetStateAsync(ApiGetStateInput input)
{
    var gameService = await _mediator.GetGameServiceAsync(input.Identity.GameId);
    var state = gameService().GetStateAsync(input.Identity.GameTableId);
    response.ResponseObject = state.Dump();
}
```

The call goes through the mediator to know which game service to call. it creates an instance of the service by passing a servicePrvidor through the constructor. the Lottery game service looks something like this:

```
public class LotteryService : BaseService, IGameBaseService
    {
       public LotteryService (IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
        {
            
        }
    }
public Task<IEnumerable<BlGameState>> GetStateAsync(int tableId)
        {
            //logic
            return something;
        }
```

```
 public class BaseService : IBaseService
    {
        protected readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        protected readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        protected readonly ICacheProvider _cache;
        protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public BaseService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _mapper = _serviceProvider.GetService<IMapper>();
            _unitOfWork = _serviceProvider.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
            _cache = _serviceProvider.GetService<ICacheProvider>();
        }
}
```

And I have registered all this in the ConfigureServices of startup:

```
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            services.AddScoped<ICacheProvider, CacheProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<IMediator, Mediator>();
```

The problem is when I run the project and call GetStateAsync, It works perfectly fine. But after calling it again looks like serviceProvider is being disposed and is not being able get a serviceProvider instance. How to solve this issue and is there a way to improve this code and architecture of getting the services?
Here is the error:

```
Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'IServiceProvider'._   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)\r\n
```

Comment: You can try injecting `IServiceScope` and call `_serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<TService>`. Don't forget to dispose it with `_serviceScope.Dispose()` after you are done with it.

Comment: @N.Dogac now it is not running. saying unable to inject IServiceScope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your Mediator is scoped service (meaning new one is created for each request and then disposed) because of that IServiceProvider instance it gets is also valid in that scope but you save it in LotteryService and try to use it after it's already disposed.

I can suggest some approaches you can consider and pick the one which fits you best.

1. Make Mediator to be a Singleton service
2. Do not cache LotteryService and make is scoped service as well
3. I don't know why LotteryService needs IServiceProvider but maybe you can pass it's dependency at the method call